# Deployed WAR can't access a file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, war

I have a spring application, and i'm trying to access a json file with the following code :

```
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("parameters.json")) {
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        parameterList = (JSONArray) obj;
    }
```

I have put the parameter.json file in the project folder and I'm accesing the file data from an angular app through a rest api, and that works fine when I run the application on local machine, but when I deploy the war file on tomcat, my application can't load the file, should I put parameter.json file somewhere else on tomcat or what is the best solution for it.

Comment: Where in your project folder do you have parameter.json?

Comment: Your code shows parameters.json, while your description shows parameter.json. Perhaps a typo?

Answer (score 2):

Your question states you are attempting to access a file called *parameter.json*, while your code excerpt shows *parameter**s**.json*. Perhaps that discrepancy indicates a typo in your source code?

If not, there are various ways to access a file from the classpath in Spring, with the first step for each being to ensure the file is in the project's *src/main/resources* directory.

You can then use one of the Spring utility classes [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html), [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) or [ResourceUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html) to get to the file. The easiest approach, though, may be to put your properties in a *.properties* file (default file name *application.properties*) and access the values using Spring's [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation:

```
@Value("${some.value.in.the.file}")
private String myValue;
```

You can use other file names as well by utilizing [@PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties", 
    "classpath:other.properties"})
public class MyClass {

    @Value("${some.value.in.the.file}")
    private String myValue;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your parameters.josn filename is exactly same in the code.
Move you parameters.json file in the resources folder and then use the classpath with the filename.

```
 try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("classpath:parameters.json")) {
   Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
   parameterList = (JSONArray) obj;
 }
```

Comment: hi, how can i write a file in resources folder

Comment: can i make modification to a file in resources folder, when the application is packaged to a WAR

Comment: You should use an external file for this purpose. You cannot modify the war/jar while it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the file under resources folder in your spring project. You should be able to access the file from that location.

Comment: can i make modification to a file in resources folder, when the application is packaged to a WAR

Answer (score 1):

FileReader is looking for a full-fledged file system like the one on your computer, but when your WAR is deployed, there just isn't one, so you have to use a different approach. You can grab your file directly from your src/main/resources folder like this

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/parameters.json");
```

Comment: can i make modification to a file in resources folder, when the application is packaged to a WAR

Comment: Unfortunately no, you'd have to unpack and repack the JAR/WAR. Were you looking for a way to have a file that you swap out without having to redeploy the application? You could do something like this but I think you'd still need to redeploy: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: This page might help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config